# angular2-jwt tokenNotExpired is not working properly

Tags: angular

`tokenNotExpired` is not working properly!

While login it matches username and password from database and also it generated token but after login page doesn't redirect to profile page. I had uploaded to cloud9.

But in local host work fine.

tokenNotExpired return false

Comment: Not sure if you've found the answer yet, but it was posted in their github. You have to pass a parameter in the `return tokenNotExpired('id_token')` reference:  https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/334#issuecomment-293968046

Answer (score 2):

use
localStorage.setItem('token', authResult.idToken)

instead of:
localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken)